# Kubernetes outages potentially being caused by kube-dns

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We've got a production kubernetes cluster that has been having a bunch of ~1-5 minute outages on a semi-regular basis.
We're trying to troubleshoot, but running into various gaps of information/knowledge and would appreciate some help.

All of our custom code & software are highly available and deployed in at least 2 replicas, and their high availability has been tested under load.

The kubernetes cluster *is* running spot instances, and when spot instances go that only contain our pods on them, things continue to run smoothly without any outages.
However, what we've noticed is that when nodes go that contain `kube-dns` on it, then we do tend to get - but not always - these outages.

We're running 1.25 on GKE and thus are restricted to use `kube-dns`. We are running 1 `kube-dns` replica per 3 nodes (we normally have 9 nodes running), **and** have specified a minimum of 3 `kube-dns` nodes via the `kube-dns-autoscaler` configmap. We're also running Istio 1.17.1 for various reasons, but *not* for mTLS. We also have a PDB on the `kube-dns` that allows only 1 disruption.

What we see, is that most of our services will start timing out in their request to each other (the `istio-proxy` access logs tends to log a `504` `UT` error), and some of the services will actually log an `EAI_AGAIN` error, which implies that the DNS timed out.
We've also got a separate application running that pings a mix of service names, as well as the service's IP address directly (starting doing this for trouble shooting purposes), and we can see that during those times when the `EAI_AGAIN` errors are happening, the IP address pings are successful, but the service name requests are not - further pointing at `kube-dns` being related to the issue.

We have also checked those service vs IP pings against pods that do and do not have an `istio-proxy` sidecar, and can see the same behaviour, implying that the problem is *not* due to `istio`.

The only thing we're starting to think of doing is to implement the `NodeLocal DNSCache` so that all nodes have a DNS cache and - might - plaster over any intermittent `kube-dns` issues. However, we're not sure if this will help, and are worry that it'd be masking a bigger problem.

We can also see this same problem running in our non-production environment, but have yet to be able to reproduce this anywhere. It just happens. Even restarting/deleting nodes don't seem to cause this to happen.

I also can't increase the logging level on `kube-dns` because GKE has locked down the deployment resource and reverts the logging levels...

We're hoping for some advice on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this.  Thank you

Comment: Can you check if the mentioned suggestions work for your environment.

(1)Using [taints](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/spot-vms#taints-tolerations) and tolerations for Spot VMs for placing system workloads like DNS in a node pool (without Spot VMs).

(2)To improve [DNS lookup](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/kube-dns#performance_limitations_with_kube-dns) times, you can either Enable NodeLocal DNSCache or Scale up kube-dns.

Comment: Scaling up the `kube-dns` has made no difference, and we haven't been able to successfully modify the `deployment` (including the taints & tolerations) because GKE is reverting it back to its defaults. That said, our intent here is to NOT have any non-spot instances. And yes, we're contemplating the `NodeLocalDNSCache`, but we're unsure if that will actually fix the problem or not.